# shrink top and bottom margin of elsarticle template

Tags: templates, elsarticle

I am using the latex template `elsarticle` from Elsevier, but I find that the top and bottom margin of this tempalte is too large, I would like to shrink the top and bottom margin. How can I do this?

PS: the `geometry` package does not work here.

The following is a smallest working set.

```
    %% Use the option review to obtain double line spacing
%% \documentclass[preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}

%% Use the options 1p,twocolumn; 3p; 3p,twocolumn; 5p; or 5p,twocolumn
%% for a journal layout:
 \documentclass[final,1p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,1p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}


\journal{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{aaaaaaaaa}

%% use optional labels to link authors explicitly to addresses:
%% \author[label1,label2]{<author name>}
%% \address[label1]{<address>}
%% \address[label2]{<address>}

\author{
abc
}

\address{}

\begin{abstract}

A deal still has not been struck to avert tax hikes and budget 
cuts after Friday's meeting between the president and congressional leaders.

WASHINGTON — U.S. Senate leaders are working to craft legislation 
by Sunday to avert the year-end "fiscal cliff" of tax hikes and 
spending cuts, but many details needed to be worked out after 
a crucial meeting with President Barack Obama on Friday.

President Obama spoke about the meeting at a press conference late afternoon.

The president said he had a “constructive meeting today” and 
he's still "modestly optimistic" that an agreement can be reached. 
But if an agreement isn't struck by the Dec. 31 deadline, 
then he will seek an up-or-down vote on a basic package that 
would include preserve tax cuts for middle-class Americans, 
while extending unemployment benefits for the long-term jobless 
and working toward a foundation for a broader deal.

President Obama says the fact that elected leadership can't make 
deadlines is mind-boggling to the average American. “We're now at the last minute”, he said.

Video: Without tax deal, vote on my plan, said Pres. Obama

The president will discuss the last-minute negotiations on
 NBC's "Meet the Press" on Sunday, the network said in a statement.



\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
%% keywords here, in the form: keyword \sep keyword

%% MSC codes here, in the form: \MSC code \sep code
%% or \MSC[2008] code \sep code (2000 is the default)



\end{keyword} 

\end{frontmatter}



\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`elsarticle` uses the `geometry` internally to set the margins, in particular, `geometry` is already loaded. So You can use e.g., `\geometry{textheight=25cm}` after `\documentclass{}`.

Answer (score 5):

Incase anyone else stumbles across this.

As a different answer, you shouldn't be directly modifying the margins if you intend on submitting it to an Elsevier Journal. The elsarticle class provides a number of different options. In particular:

```
\documentclass[1p, final]{elsarticle}
```

Note the 1p here, this is a model 1+ journal and typically has larger spacing
There are other options.

```
\documentclass[3p, final]{elsarticle}
\documentclass[3p, twocolumn, final]{elsarticle}
\documentclass[5p, final]{elsarticle}
```

The 5p style is always two column.
I would suggest moving to the 5p format, or if you don't want a two column layout then move to 3p. Don't change the internal document settings.

You can find the full documentation for the class here:

http://cdn.elsevier.com/assets/pdf_file/0011/109388/elsdoc.pdf

The margins for the different styles are:

- 1+ journals with a text area of 384pt × 562pt or 13.5cm × 19.75cm or 5.3in × 7.78in, single column style only.
- 3+ journals with a text area of 468pt × 622pt or 16.45cm × 21.9cm or 6.5in × 8.6in, single column style.
- twocolumn
  should be used along with 3p option if the journal is 3+ with the same text area as above, but double column style.
- 5p
  5+ with a text area of 522pt × 682pt or 18.35cm × 24cm or 7.22in × 9.45in, double column style only.

Comment: I think this should be accepted answer. Interestingly, I couldn't able to find these options in their web page. Also, the link in the answer needs to be updated.